# How do I monitor downloads in Orangedox?

Tags: orangedox

I've loaded it up and run a test - I've downloaded a file from my account using Orangedox. I still have no notification that its been downloaded. How do I get a notification?

Answer (score 1):

In order to see how many times & when the file was downloaded you'll need to login to Orangedox and browse the file that you're tracking (see screenshot)

[image: downloads]

As for email notifications .. that is something we are looking to add into Pro in the near future.